# Search DOM for elements based on part of the class name

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to write a Greasemonkey script to delete specific HTML elements from the view of a web app I use frequently. These elements are identified by class names like `"sidebar-2K8pFh"`. I suspect these are hashes that will change every time the web app is updated. If I use `document.getElementsByClassName()`, such a change will break my script, so instead, I want to find and delete every element on the page belonging to a class that would match the regular expression `/^sidebar-.*$/`. (Only one such element exists on the page; I'm not sure why it's a class instead of an ID.)

How do I search the DOM for elements with classes with names that match a *pattern* rather than an exact string? It doesn't have to be regex; I just need a way to filter elements based on their class names without treating those class names as atomic units.

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll('[class=^sidebar]')`

Comment: @trinalbadger587 You mean `^=` instead of `=^`.